# Values null when passed from another page using modal and jquery

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am having problem on passing values into another page using jQuery and modal. So here is my code.

Firing up the modal:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' data_project='$row[PROJECT_NAME]' data_headmark='$row[HEAD_MARK]' data_id='$row[ID]'></input>";

echo '<button type="button" name="qcreject" id="qcreject" class="btn btn-primary btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#qcRejectModal"> 
                <span style="font-size:35px"> '.$row['PROJECT_NAME'].' / <b>'.$_POST["hm"].'</b>/'.$row['ID'].' ~ FAIL</span></button>';

 <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              This is the confirmation window to PASS all the Quality Control for, <br/><br/>
                              PROJECT : <b>'.$row['PROJECT_NAME'].'</b>
                              HEADMARK : <b>'.$row['HEAD_MARK'].'</b>
                              ID : <b>'.$row['ID'].'
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea name="reasonForRejection" id="reasonForRejection" class="form-control" placeholder="Reason for rejection" rows="2" required></textarea>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" name="rejectbutton" id="rejectbutton" class="btn btn-danger">Confirm REJECT!</button>
                  </div>
```

and when user click the reject button it should pass PROJECT_NAME, HEAD_MARK, ID and values in the textarea to the testClass.php.

jQuery is,

```
$('#rejectbutton').click(function() {

        $.post("testClass.php",{
        projectName : this.getAttribute("data_project"), 
        headMark : this.getAttribute("data_headmark"),
        id : this.getAttribute("data_id"),
        reasonReject : this.getAttribute("reasonForRejection")});
    });
```

and inside the testClass.php

```
    echo 'TEST CLASS WORKS';

$val1 = $_POST["projectName"];
$val2 = $_POST["headMark"];
$val3 = $_POST["id"];
$val4 = $_POST["reasonReject"];

var_dump($val1);
var_dump($val2);
var_dump($val3);
var_dump($val4);
```

unfortunately all the values I'm getting in the testClass are null

```
TEST CLASS WORKSstring(0) ""
string(0) ""
string(0) ""
string(0) ""
```

Comment: Where have you defined "data_project" in html? and the others data-XX ...

Comment: oops my bad, its before the modal tag,

 echo "<input type='hidden' data_project='$row[PROJECT_NAME]' data_headmark='$row[HEAD_MARK]' data_id='$row[ID]'></input>";

Comment: "this" inside  $('#rejectbutton').click() refers to rejectbutton. Check @Manibharathi answer ... and read about .data http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `id` attribute in your hidden field then use that in `js` like below code.

```
echo "<input type='hidden' data_project='$row[PROJECT_NAME]' data_headmark='$row[HEAD_MARK]' data_id='$row[ID]' id="data_field" />";

// your codes

$('#rejectbutton').click(function() {
     var myData = $('#data_field');
     $.post("testClass.php",{
     projectName : myData.attr("data_project"), 
     headMark : myData.attr("data_headmark"),
     id : myData.attr("data_id"),
     reasonReject : $("#reasonForRejection").val() 
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this code:

```
$('#rejectbutton').click(function() {
    $.post("testClass.php",{
    projectName : this.getAttribute("data_project"), 
    headMark : this.getAttribute("data_headmark"),
    id : this.getAttribute("data_id"),
    reasonReject : this.getAttribute("reasonForRejection")});
});
```

it assumes, that when the element with id `#rejectbutton` is clicked, which is:

```
<button type="button" name="rejectbutton" id="rejectbutton" class="btn btn-danger">Confirm REJECT!</button>
```

It has the attributes you want on it, but it doesn't. Also, you are trying to get the attributes using `getAttribute()` - why don't you use the jquery method?

---

this is how you do it. Update your HTML to be like this:

```
<button
    type="button"
    name="rejectbutton"
    id="rejectbutton"
    class="btn btn-danger" 
    data_project="some project name",
    headMark="some head mark",
    data_id="1234",
    reasonForRejection="some reason here"
    >Confirm REJECT!</button>
```

Then update your JS to get those attributes in your post request like this:

```
$('#rejectbutton').click(function() {
    $.post("testClass.php", {
        projectName : $(this).attr('data_project'),
        headMark : $(this).attr('headMark'),
        id : $(this).attr('data_id'),
        reasonReject : $(this).attr('reasonForRejection'),
    });
});
```

Comment: it works for the project, headmark and id but not the text area. because I keep the textarea separated.